# When you flip a fraction to remove the negative exponent, do you flip all of what's on numerator and denominator?

Tags: exponentiation

**When you flip a fraction to remove the negative exponent, do you flip all of what's on numerator and denominator? Or do you only do that with variables**

**Such as:**

(-7a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>3</sup>c<sup>0</sup>/3a<sup>3</sup>b<sup>4</sup>c<sup>3</sup>
)<sup>-4</sup>

**Will it be written as:**

(3a<sup>3</sup>b<sup>4</sup>c<sup>3</sup>/7a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>3</sup>c<sup>0</sup>)<sup>4</sup>

**or**

(3a<sup>3</sup>b<sup>4</sup>c<sup>3</sup>/-7a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>3</sup>c<sup>0</sup>)<sup>4</sup>

**or**

(3a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>3</sup>c<sup>0</sup>/7a<sup>3</sup>b<sup>4</sup>c<sup>3</sup>
)<sup>-4</sup>

**or**

(7a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>3</sup>c<sup>0</sup>/3a<sup>3</sup>b<sup>4</sup>c<sup>3</sup>
)<sup>-4</sup>

Comment: The second one.

Comment: In that particular case, the first and second are equivalent (since the exponent is even, the minus sign dissapears). But the second expression is the correct one in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

just write it out step by step:

$$\left(\frac{-7a^2b^3c^0}{3a^3b^4c^3}\right)^{-4} =  \frac{1}{\left(\frac{-7a^2b^3c^0}{3a^3b^4c^3}\right)^{4}} = \frac{(3a^3b^4c^3)^4}{(-7a^2b^3c^0)^4}$$ 
So your second option is correct. Hope this helps.